# Javascript function. Don't understand how function inside self-function work

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

would like to ask about a JavaScript function.

I don't understand below function, I thought at line 4 `fib(n-1)` will return `1` and the latter `fib(n-2)` will return `0`, and then they both add together as 1.

May I know why the final result for `f(10);` will be `55`, can't get my head around this.

Anyone can help to explain to me what happening behind the scene, please?

Thanks! ;)

```
var f = function fib(n) {
    if (n === 0) return 0;
    if (n === 1) return 1;
    if (n > 1) return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);      // *2
};
f(10);       // 55
```

ref: https://slides.com/concise/js/fullscreen#/35

Comment: This is a really basic recursive function, if you don't understand it, you don't understand recursion, so you should look it up.

Answer (score 8):

Like this. This is a typical recursive function, with two base cases and one recursive step.

Remember that if `n` is 10, then `fib(n - 1)` is `fib(9)`, and so on:

```
fib(10) = fib(9) + fib(8) = 34 + 21 = 55
fib(9)  = fib(8) + fib(7) = 21 + 13 = 34
fib(8)  = fib(7) + fib(6) = 13 +  8 = 21
fib(7)  = fib(6) + fib(5) =  8 +  5 = 13
fib(6)  = fib(5) + fib(4) =  5 +  3 =  8
fib(5)  = fib(4) + fib(3) =  3 +  2 =  5
fib(4)  = fib(3) + fib(2) =  2 +  1 =  3
fib(3)  = fib(2) + fib(1) =  1 +  1 =  2
fib(2)  = fib(1) + fib(0) =  1 +  0 =  1
fib(1)  =                              1
fib(0)  =                              0
```

Side note: Although your example is a good illustration of recursive functions, it's an extremely inefficient way to calculate fibonacci numbers. A much better approach is to use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to eliminate the bulk of the inefficiency:

```js
var fib = (function () {
  var cache = [0, 1];
  
  return function fib(num) {
    if (!(num in cache)) { 
        cache[num] = fib(num - 1) + fib(num - 2);
    }
    return cache[num];
  };
})();

console.log(fib(10));
```

http://jsperf.com/fibonacci-memoization-2015-04-01

Comment: great answer! I understand recursion but it's always difficult to me to explain to people!!!

Comment: Hey JLRishe, thanks for your details explanation! I find this really helpful by breaking it down, Is this a common way (break it down) to find out the solution for recursive function, or it is just me?

Comment: @NixSiow When you're starting to learn about recursion, this is a good way to break it down, and sometimes even experienced programmers will need to do this, but ideally, you should eventually gain the ability to see what a recursive function is doing without going throught the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

this is called "recursive function" which one function calls itself.

basically there is no restriction (in terms of the OS)  of doing so, a function basically gets interpreted/compiled to assembly code , and this assembly code can be copied and re-run with different (or the same) arguments.